# How can I add the image so it will show the image not only the location?

Tags: php, html, mysql, image

Hello I'm new with this and I'm trying to figure out how PHP and MySQL work.
I'm trying to show an image on the page but now I only get text.

in phpMyAdmin I have created the following table.

`dvdshop2`.
 with dvd that has 5 categories.

```
 description       text      255.
 id int  primary_key  auto increment.
 image varchar 255.  
 price decimal 10,2.
 title varchar 100.
```

I have one movie in my database with a picture like this.

```
id     title              price     description     image
1     Star Wars    12.99     sci-fi movie     /dvdshop2/images/sw.jpg
```

I run xampp as a sever where `dvdshop2` is the working folder in my htdocs folder.
I want the data from the database to show up with the picture `sw.jpg` not the text `/dvdshop2/images/sw.jpg` when I open the page in my browser.

Here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";


$conn = new mysqli("127.0.0.1","root","","dvdshop2");

if ($conn->connect_error) {
 die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM dvd";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Title: " . $row["title"]. " " . "<br>" .     "- Price:" . $row["price"] . "<br>" . " Description: " . " " . $row["description"] . " " . "<br>" . " image: " . "<br>" . $row["image"] . "<br>";
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>  

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Image tag is `<img src="">` it is described in any html manual.

Comment: You need to learn a bit more html: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img

Comment: @VictorSmt if you're going to edit a question to format a table at least use an ASCII art tool such as https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/

Comment: This is HTML 101 stuff really, and not a PHP/mysql issue. Learning HTML before PHP is essential to any web designer/developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just outputting the text:

```
$row["image"]
```

Instead, use an HTML `img` element where the text is the URL of the image:

```
'<img src="' . $row["image"] . '" />"
```

So the result would be:

```
<img src="/dvdshop2/images/sw.jpg" />
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer to my problem really appreciate it.